# Prove that the product of a constant and a continuous function is continuous.

Tags: limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

My attempt

A function $f$ is continuous if $\forall ε_1>0\,\,\exists δ_1$ such that $|x-a|<δ_1\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<ε_1$ .

Now we can multiply $ε_1$ with |k| to obtain $|x-a|<δ_1\Rightarrow |k||f(x)-f(a)|<$|k|$ε_1$

$|kf(x)-kf(a)|$ < $|k|ε_1$

Any Positive Real Number can be written as a product of 2 real numbers thus we define $ε_2$=$|k|ε_1$.

Since $\forall ε_1\,\exists δ_1$ and $\forall ε_2\,\exists ε_1$ , we can conclude $\forall ε_2\,\exists δ_1$ where  $|x-a|<δ_1\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<ε_2$

My proof is a bit different from the traditional proof as I use stuff like any positive real number can be represented by product of two positive real numbers instead of letting ε be some value and manipulating it. Also I'm confused whether the last statement should be $|x-a|<δ_1$  or  $|x-a|<δ_2$ where $δ_2$ is a new defined $δ$

NOTE- $|k|$ is assumed to be greater than 0 as the proof for k=0 is really easy

Comment: The title of your question speaks only about _continuous_ functions -- why does your attempt start pulling in _uniform_ continuity?

Comment: Corrected thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, leaving the quantifiers on $x$ and $y$ implicit (or, in one case, at the end of your sentence, such that it's not clear whether $\varepsilon_1$ and $\delta_1$ can depend on them or not) makes the structure of your reasoning extremely unclear -- to the point where that alone will lead to the proof being rejected in a typical real-analysis course where being careful about quantifier is _part of the point_ that students are supposed to learn.

Comment: Your post still says "continuous" in the title and "uniformly continuous" in the body. Given the sloppiness about how $x$ and $y$ are quantified, it is not even clear from inspecting your definition which of them you mean.

Comment: Edited, really sorry for the sloppiness. I'm not doing a formal course so it shouldn't matter but I should've been careful.

Comment: "Any Positive Real Number can be written as a product of 2 real numbers thus we define ε2"  Then $\epsilon_2$ is no langer *any* value, but a specific value.  You need to prove this for *any* $\epsilon$ not merely *some* epsilon that is a product of a constant and some *other* specific epsilon.

Comment: $\forall \epsilon_1$ doesn't make sense. If you want to take a generic epsilon you should write it as $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very basic proof, but you seem to be confused. Let's take it slowly. Define $g(x)=kf(x)$. This is the sum of a constant and a continuous function alright. Let $\epsilon$ be a positive integer. What we need to show is that there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow |g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$. Now, from the continuity of $f$, we deduce that for the positive integer $\epsilon/k$ there is a positive integer $\delta'$ so that $|x-y|<\delta'\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/k$. Then we need only take $\delta=\delta'$ to have $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$.

Now, this sort of formal, cumbersome manipulation is really not the point of calculus. As you get acquainted with basic notation, you will soon adopt a more relaxed stance towards this, to the point that you'll be showing that $|g(x)-g(y)|$ is less than some function of $\epsilon$ whose limit at $0$ is $0$ and declairing "well, since $\epsilon$ can be any positive number, that proves the continuity of $g$". You just need to make sure that you practice understanding the image behind the notation.

I also must note that the sequence definition of continuity is a proper way to prove this fact, and you might want to look it up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is my attempt at proving logically correct though. I understand that since we can get a δ' for ϵ, we can get one for ϵ/|k| which would allow us to get |g(x)−g(y)| < ϵ at the end but is the approach using two epsilons is correct? My high school teacher told us that if he gave us any value of ϵ we should be able to give him a value of δ. So if we take the value he gives us as $ϵ_2$ then all I have to do is find the corresponding $ϵ_1$ which would then allow me to find a δ. Please point out the flaws in my reasoning if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: "but is the approach using two epsilons is correct?"  No.  " if he gave us any value of ϵ".  The key word there is *any*.  epsilon can be *any* real value.  "So if we take the value he gives us as ϵ2" Then is is now *one* specific value, not *any* value. " is find the corresponding ϵ1 which would"  But that is *ONE* value.  Not any value.

Comment: @fleablood By taking it $ϵ_2$ I just meant calling it that. So lets say k=3 and he gives me a value of 15, I can find $ϵ_1$ which would be 5. For $ϵ_1$ = 5, I would be able to find a delta.

Comment: The thing is if the teacher gave you an $\epsilon$ then you must use *that* epsilon.  Sure you can call it $\epsilon_1$ if you want but then you must *use* $\epsilon_1$.  You *can't* use a different $\epsilon_2$.

Comment: But you must be able to do that for *ANY* epsilon.  Not just epsilon = 5.

Comment: I get what you mean but I don't see why I can't use different $ϵ$ . All I have to show is that if he gives me a positive real value(ϵ), I can give him a positive real value(δ) for all real values he gives. He gives me a value  $ϵ_2$, I will always be able to give him a δ because all I have to do is divide the value given by him by |k| and find a δ for that value. The key point I think you're missing is that whenever two positive real numbers are divided, the result is a positive real number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77375/discussion-between-arjun-nigam-and-fleablood).

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is fine but you are mangling the concept that that these proofs must hold for *ANY* $\epsilon$ and not just a specific one.

To word the proof you want I think you should do this.

$\forall \epsilon > 0$ [It is an abuse of notation to say $\forall \epsilon_1$.  THe indexing of $\ _1$ implies you have a *specific* value in mind but we are making a statement about *all* possible values..]

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta_{\epsilon}$  [The delta is dependent upon the $\epsilon$.  Must proofs don't bother with the index for the delta but I like to because it indicates that the $\delta$ value is specific to whatever the $\epsilon$ value is.

So that $|x -a| < \delta_\epsilon \implies |f(x) -f(a)| < \epsilon$.

So $|kf(x)-kf(a)|<|k|\epsilon = \epsilon_2$.

Now your error is in thinking that *starting* with $\epsilon$ and proving something about a *different* $\epsilon_2$ is in any way relevant. We must prove something for our *first* epsilon.

But that is salvageable.

We can say.  For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $\epsilon_1$ and a $\delta_{\epsilon_1}$ so that $|k|\epsilon_1 = \epsilon$ and $|x-a|<\delta_{\epsilon_1}\implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon_1 \implies |kf(x) - kf(a)| < |k|\epsilon_1 = \epsilon$.

==== old ====

For $f$ and for any $\epsilon_1 >0$ you can find a $\delta$ **that is dependent upon both $f$ and upon $\epsilon$** (we can call it $\delta_{f, \epsilon_1}$ so that if $|x-a|< \delta_{f, \epsilon_1}$ then $|f(x) -f(a)| < \epsilon_1$.

So for the SAME $\epsilon_1$ we can find an $\epsilon_2$ so that $\epsilon_1 = |k|\epsilon_2$ and $\epsilon_2 = \frac{\epsilon_1}{|k|}$ (assuming $k \ne 0$) and for *that* $\epsilon_2$ there is a $\delta_{f,\epsilon_2}$ so that if $|x - a| < \delta_{f,\epsilon_2}$ then $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon_2$.  And therefore $|k(f(x)) - ka| < |k|\epsilon_2 = \epsilon_1$.

So we have proven for all $\epsilon_1$ (!!!***NOT***!!! a *different* $\epsilon_2$ but the *FIRST* $\epsilon_1$ then there exists a $\delta_{kf, \epsilon_1} = \delta_{f, \epsilon_2}=\delta_{f,\frac {\epsilon_1}{|k|}}$, that does ... the magic bullet stuff.

The thing is you use the new epsilon, to find a new delta, but you use the new delta to apply *back* to the *old* epsilon.  We can't try to just apply it to a new epsilon altogether.